# Core.logic misses solution with fd/* when a (correct, integral, non-negative) domain is given for an lvar being multiplied, works without domain

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

`fd/*` seems to have problems handling negative numbers, even if they are only constants. And it does work in many situations. What am I doing wrong?

```
(require '[clojure.core.logic :as l]
         '[clojure.core.logic.fd :as fd])

; Works, returns (1):
(l/run* [q] 
        (fd/* -1 q -1))

; Works, returns (1):
(l/run* [q] 
        (fd/in q (fd/domain 1))
        (fd/* -1 q -1))

; Fails, returns ():
(l/run* [q] 
        (fd/in q (fd/domain 0 1))
        (fd/* -1 q -1))
```

Comment: Hmmm. Taking a look. Same issue if I make it (fd/* 1 q -1) and then specify negative domain values. fd/interval shares the same issue. Unfortunately it's 2230 and my ability to grok core.logic.fd/*c right now is limited. I'm looking at the constraints it's deriving and there are a lot of -ves being bandied about. Maybe another look tomorrow, then possibly one to raise as a bug... I suspect the single valued domain works due to the singleton-dom? check shortcutting things.

Comment: Actually I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195493/core-logic-finite-domain-with-ve-values?rq=1 - my hunch about the negative constraints appears to have been correct. Maybe I'll take a dig and see if I can put together a patch tomorrow.

Comment: Not flagging as dupe - that one pertains to negative domains, this one to negative results. Same root cause, same unimplemented behaviour, different expression so worth searching for.